# Testing WCF services without starting them

Tags: c#, wcf, unit-testing

I want to test my WCF classes (Integration testing) but I don't want to start them as WCF services.

Everything works well but in some cases I need to read IncomingMessageHeaders from OperationContext. I wonder if this can be done?

What I've learned to far is that I can create OperationContext and use it. But I'd need to create it via ChannelFactory which requires Binding (and then Endpoint). What I need (probably) is somehow make a local binding to my implementation class. Is this possible?

Comment: I just faced the same kind of problem and I've been advised to do as Rick Liddle said. It seems to be the best approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to handle this is to use [DI/IoC](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) to abstract OperationContext out to an interface and then use a [mocking framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) like [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) or [Rhino](http://hibernatingrhinos.com/open-source/rhino-mocks) to implement that interface. When you test, your mocking framework will provide an instance of that new class in place of OperationContext. That completely removes your dependency on something external during testing.

Comment: Rick, I just did what you'd suggested. Turned out to be much easier than my initial approach, especially since I already use IoC for my services. Thanks.

Comment: @kostassoid - Glad to hear it. I was the same way initially... it seemed like it would be a crazy amount of work, and the initial setup was a little time-consuming but it's been well worth it.

Answer (score 2):

The alternative is to make each WCF method a one-liner, calling a business logic layer, which you will be able to unit test without having to worry about WCF implementation details.

Comment: I like your idea of keeping business logic out of the service, unless absolutely necessary. Then, WCF is only used as a way to expose your business logic. This will make unit testing easier, as well as giving you the flexibility to easily use your business logic in other non-WCF applications.

Comment: My services methods are usually one-liners. But what if I need to provide some user token to identify context? This way my methods will never be one-liners. Of course, it's only infrastructure, not an actual logic. Still, I don't mind testing both.

Comment: Of course sometimes you need some stuff from the request to send to the actual business logic. In these cases you WCF method will propably be more than a one-liner and possibly needs testing. Some frameworks makes this easy and some don't. But I think the business logic is in most cases more important to test, than testing code fetching stuff from the request. But I totally agree with you. Sometimes you need to test both. In this case my proposal doesn't work :)